# Use Relative layout with Scrollable Constraint layout to achieve a freeze panes effect

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I am pretty new to Android Studio, so please forgive any thing which may have been obvious but I did not pick up.

I would like help in the below situation -

I have setup two layouts:

Relative Layout & a Constraint Layout (which is nested in ScrollView).

I wanted to keep some views to be visible all the time, so I put them in a Relative Layout. I put all other views in a constraint layout which is scrollable, since the number of elements do not fit in the screen.

I am trying to get the same effect which you get when you freeze the top row of an excel worksheet.

I tried to adjust the layout height property of the Constraint Layout but I can't seem to get it right. What I want is to anchor my Constraint Layout below the Relative Layout.

I have attached my code.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Regards,
Ravi.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.android.raviagl.netlandingcostcalculate.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sap"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nlc"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="SAP"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset_all"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nlc"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="NLC"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

            android:id="@+id/constraint_layout_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/dp"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/allowance"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/gst"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/allowance" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/slab"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gst" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/slab_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slab">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_slab_value"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Use Fixed Amount"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_slab_percent"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Use SAP Percent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sell_through"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/slab" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sell_out"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sell_through" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/display"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sell_out" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/display_radio_group"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_display_value"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Use Fixed Amount"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/radio_display_percent"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="31dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Use SAP Percent"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="248dp" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/tie_up"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/handling"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tie_up" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/cash_discount"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/handling" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_dp"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="DP"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_allowance"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Allowance"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/allowance"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_gst"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="GST"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/gst"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_slab"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Slab"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/slab"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_sell_through"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Sell Through"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/sell_through"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_sell_out"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Sell Out"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/sell_out"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_display"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Display"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/display"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_tie_up"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Tie UP"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/tie_up"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_handling"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Handling"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/handling"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/d_cash_discount"
                android:layout_width="175dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Cash Discount"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/cash_discount"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options to consider here but I think the one that requires the least amount of refactoring your layout is this:

- Add `android:layout_below` attribute to your `ScrollView` and position it under one the views that are fixed. It doesn't matter which one as long as they are the same height:

  ```
  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below="@id/sap">
  ```
- Decrease (or remove) the top margin from the `EditText` with the ID `android:id="@+id/dp"`to eliminate unnecessary space on the top.

All that being said since you are using fixed widths for all the views in your layout you might run into some problems with displaying it on different screen sizes. For example the three fixed views on the top might overlap each other if there is not enough horizontal space. This could possibly be resolved by using other layouts (such as `ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout`) as root and/or not using fixed widths. However, this would require much more refactoring that the solution above.

Comment: Hi plaskoff,

Thank you for replying,

Usimg the layout_below property of scrollView did help to achieve what I wanted.

You are very much right about the fixed width of the elements in the top. I did consider it and it was the skeleton of the app which I wanted to get right first that  I wanted to finetune later. 

Thank you once more for the help. It is because of helpful people like you that the world seems such a wonderful place.

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider upvoting/marking my answer as accepted if it has helped you.

Comment: I have marked your answer as accepted and since I am new and joined recently, my upvote is not showing. Anyways, I've upvoted too. :)